# value too long for type character varying(1)

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy my app on `heroku`, everything went well, all the files were uploaded, but as soon as I ran `heroku run python manage.py migrate` it gave the following error for a particular field(choices field).

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)
```

The model in which the field is present is:

**models.py**

```
class Api(models.Model):
    User = get_user_model()
    notice_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    notice_desc = models.TextField()
    notice_file = models.FileField(upload_to="notice_files/", null=True, blank=True)
    notice_author = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='admin')
    notice_valid_till = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    notice_publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    choices = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I tried varying the length of the `choices` field, but it didn't help. Can  anyone help me out with this.

**Edit**

```
Running python3 manage.py migrate on ⬢ polar-caverns-67420... up, run.5910 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, api, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, feedback, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying accounts.0001_initial... OK
  Applying accounts.0002_account_confirm_password... OK
  Applying accounts.0003_auto_20171106_0842... OK
  Applying accounts.0004_images... OK
  Applying accounts.0005_auto_20171106_1137... OK
  Applying accounts.0006_profile_user... OK
  Applying accounts.0007_remove_profile_user... OK
  Applying accounts.0008_profile_user... OK
  Applying accounts.0009_auto_20171108_0637... OK
  Applying accounts.0010_auto_20171108_0653... OK
  Applying accounts.0011_auto_20171123_1608... OK
  Applying accounts.0012_auto_20171123_1753... OK
  Applying accounts.0013_auto_20171124_0258... OK
  Applying accounts.0014_auto_20171124_0300... OK
  Applying accounts.0015_profile_roll_no... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying api.0001_initial... OK
  Applying api.0002_api_choices...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 87, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 429, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)
```

Comment: I think the error is not related to this part of your code, a full stacktrace might help

Comment: I have edited the question. Have a look now.

Comment: I think that you should check your migration files `api.0002_api_choice` and `api.0001_initial` and fix length issue in them too

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: You had max_length = 1 somewhere and you are trying to add a record to that field with a length greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem when I switched from local development with sqlite to heroku with postgresql and for this reason I came back to the local development but this time with postgres and after many tests, **I finally deleted all my migrations and created and migrated them again from scratch and It worked.**